# Problems with Moonlight on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, firefox, silverlight, linux-mint, moonlight

I am just started to using Linux Mint.

I wanted to view a Microsoft Silverlight page, but, i needed Microsoft Silverlight. Microsoft redirected me, with my FireFox on Linux Mint, to Moonlight. I downloaded and installed the plugin. Restarted my Firefox serveral times, but still, the page is telling me to install Microsoft Silverlight.

Help?

PS: No it does not help giving the link, it's in Dutch.

Comment: It would actually help to give the link to the site, whether it's in Dutch or not.  Then we can at least investigate the Silverlight applet in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now. Just now, an update came out, updated Moonlight, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

One thing it might be worth trying is to install Moonlight through your package manager rather than from the webpage.

The Debian/Ubuntu package for this is `moonlight-plugin-mozilla`, so it should be the same on Linux Mint.  I would use `aptitude` (command-line) or `synaptic` (GUI) to search for and then install this package.

If you use `synaptic`  just search for `moonlight` and then pick the plugin to install.

e.g. if you use `aptitude` then:

```
sudo aptitude install moonlight-plugin-mozilla
```

However, bear in mind that Moonlight isn't 100% complete, so it doesn't match Silverlight feature for feature.  It's perhaps possible that for the page you're looking at Moonlight isn't up to speed.

Comment: it's still not working. Maybe it stil helps to give you a site: http://wolfert.swp.nl

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

it solves your problem. It s not moonlight, it s PIPELIGHT and it works on linux mint

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Specifically, add the instructions for how to install it, and possibly where you found this solution. Thanks!